# Best software / tool to downgrades Git branches?

Tags: java, git

Good evening,

Please excuse me if this is not the correct place to ask this question. I will gladly post it elsewhere would you take the time to show me where.

I am starting a new pet project where I'll work with an existing Java git project. Said project has many branches, which got stopped at some point

```
Main Project
- Develop (up to date)
- Saison 4 (ended 2017)
- Saison 3 (ended 2016)
- Saison 2 (ended 2015)
```

As you can guess, the branches stopped at various past dates. I want to downgrade from the develop branch to the Saison 2 branch, keeping the major bugfixes, security updates and various improvements of the develop branch, while getting back to various features of the Saison 2 branch.

What would be the best software / tool to use in order to do that ?

I tried to simply compare the two branches within Eclipse, but the huge number of files makes it crash (4,266 files) and the Synchronize view is not really helping.

Thank you for any suggestion !

Answer (score 1):

This probably belongs on one of the other stacks, but if you are happy with Eclipse then that is what I'd use.  Start with a copy of the Saison2 branch and the Develop branch each as different projects, you'll need to avoid Saison 3/4 branch stuff in the Develop code base, and copy/paste or re-write/re-implement as needed.

I'd also ask over on stackoverflow and softwareengineering.se

Comment: I already asked on StackOverflow and was sent here (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52374450/best-software-tool-to-downgrades-git-branches) ). thank you for your input ! I guess I'll stuck to Eclipse since that's what I use the most

Comment: @ivanivan: Software-recommendation questions are explicitly off-topic on both [softwareengineering.se] and [so]. [softwareengineering.se] even has an explicit close reason in the off-topic menu for software recommendations. Please, don't recommend sites whose scope you don't fully understand, it leads to negative experiences all around: the OP has their questions downvoted, closed, and deleted, the [softwareengineering.se] and [so] users get annoyed by off-topic questions, and you receive negative comments.

Comment: Personally, I would use Beyond Compare for the fiel comparisions. But, whatever you use, you have a hard task ahead of you, and I don't eveny you. Hasve you looked at GitLens?